Preserving finite index via profinite completion
Let $G$ be a finitely generated residually finite group and let $H\leq G$ of finite index. Denote by $\hat{G}$ the profinite completion of $G$ and by $\bar{H}$ the topological closure of $H$ in $\hat{G}$. It is true that $|\hat{G}:\bar{H}|=|G:H|$?

Hint: The claim about indices is a consequence of the group isomorphism $\hat{G}/\overline{H}\cong G/H$. In fact, we have $\overline{H}=\hat{H}$ and the functor $\hat{(-)}$ preserves quotients (more generally, colimits).

Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.
